# Android:click effect in a linearlayout

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android programing and just started to play around with android.

I have a linearlayout which contains 2 textviews. When i click on the linearlayout, the textcolor in one textview and background in the other textview must change for a small peroid of time. It should return to its orginal textcolor and background after the click.

The problem is that the `setOnClickListener()` must be implemented on the linearlayout.

This is the code

```
                           <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_logout"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/logout_home_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_logout"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Log Out"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here the logout_home_icon is an image(.png)..plsss help.

Comment: So, what is the problem? What is your code?

Answer (score 2):

Implement setOnClickListener on layout itself and in the callback ,i.e. onClick() ,
you will get reference to LinearLayout , use that reference to get ChildView using getChildAt(position)
Then change accordingly.